# System lags/freezes, dmesg shows GPU errors and faux USB disconnect - what to do?

Tags: freeze, gpu, dmesg, lag

I use GNU/Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit on an Intel i5 3570K machine with a discrete nVIDIA-based graphics card.

Recently there was a power outage in my neighborhood. After it, I couldn't boot my machine and had to replace my PSU. Now my machine boots and works. H-o-w-e-v-e-r, I've been getting strange error messages in my log, regarding my GPU and regarding a supposed disconnection and re-connection of some USB devices (which were not disconnected):

```
[  167.367247] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics SM Warp Exception on (GPC 0, TPC 0): Out Of Range Address
[  167.367254] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics SM Global Exception on (GPC 0, TPC 0): Physical Multiple Warp Errors
[  167.367260] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x504648=0x15000e 0x504650=0x24 0x504644=0x13eff2 0x50464c=0x7f
[  167.367293] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics SM Warp Exception on (GPC 1, TPC 0): Out Of Range Address
[  167.367296] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics SM Global Exception on (GPC 1, TPC 0): Physical Multiple Warp Errors
[  167.367298] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x50c648=0x3a000e 0x50c650=0x24 0x50c644=0x13eff2 0x50c64c=0x7f
[  167.367329] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics SM Warp Exception on (GPC 2, TPC 0): Out Of Range Address
[  167.367332] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics SM Global Exception on (GPC 2, TPC 0): Physical Multiple Warp Errors
[  167.367335] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x514648=0x1e000e 0x514650=0x24 0x514644=0x13eff2 0x51464c=0x7f
[  167.367362] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ChID 0010, Class 0000a0c0, Offset 00001b0c, Data 00000000
[  167.709832] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:02:00: GPU-a503e5ff-3740-8318-878a-a21e528c646c
[  167.709836] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000010, engmask 00000111, intr 10000000
[  168.045998] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:02:00: GPU-a503e5ff-3740-8318-878a-a21e528c646c
[  168.046003] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000010, engmask 00000111, intr 10000000
[  168.407864] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:02:00: GPU-a503e5ff-3740-8318-878a-a21e528c646c
[  168.407869] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000010, engmask 00000111, intr 10000000
[  168.752045] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:02:00: GPU-a503e5ff-3740-8318-878a-a21e528c646c
[  168.752049] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000010, engmask 00000111, intr 10000000
[  169.110574] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:02:00: GPU-a503e5ff-3740-8318-878a-a21e528c646c
[  169.110578] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000010, engmask 00000111, intr 10000000
[  169.479404] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:02:00: GPU-a503e5ff-3740-8318-878a-a21e528c646c
[  169.479408] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000010, engmask 00000111, intr 10000000
[  169.819896] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:02:00: GPU-a503e5ff-3740-8318-878a-a21e528c646c
[  169.819900] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000010, engmask 00000111, intr 10000000
[  529.780140] usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  530.008396] usb 2-1.6: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  530.105253] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0084
[  530.105258] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  530.105260] usb 2-1.6: Product: Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse 
[  530.105263] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Microsoft 
[  530.109030] input: Microsoft  Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/0003:045E:0084.0003/input/input21
[  530.109415] hid-generic 0003:045E:0084.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft  Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse ] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0
[  790.118073] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:02:00: GPU-a503e5ff-3740-8318-878a-a21e528c646c
[  790.118077] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000018, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
[  790.213339] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000018, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
[  790.308416] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000018, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
[  790.421164] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000018, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
[  790.521354] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000018, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
[  790.620486] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000018, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
[  790.712321] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000018, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
[  790.808216] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:02:00): 31, Ch 00000018, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
```

and whenever I try to put some significant load on the system (e.g. building source project from sources) - everything tends to freeze up or lag terribly, including the UI usually. This did not use to happen.

On the other hand, I've also recently `apt-get upgrade`d myself with a new version of the Linux kernel (whatever the distribution provides, not custom-built).

My questions are:

- Is what I'm seeing necessarily a hardware issue?
- If so, what could be the problem?
- If not, what parts of the OS or user apps could be responsible?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an outdated question, but, in case someone had a similar issue, I would recommend checking the Xid error messages from Nvidia website, [in this link](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/index.html)

For example, you can see that errors number 13 and 31 are related to a user application. This could be software you use that mishandle the usage or access of the memory.